# sas perl regular expression (search exact match for multiple value and replace with one )

Tags: regex, sas, pcre

I need to search for most of the connecting words in a paragraph and replace with blank.

For example :

```
You are a boy .......
Is he a scientist ......
```

I need to remove words like you, i, we, they, he, she, it etc...

I come up with this regex but it will not work if the word is side by side..

```
content  = left(prxchange('s/ you | are | he / /',-1,cat(' ',content,' ')));
```

My results will not remove the word "are". I put blank in the front and back to make sure that it is an exact match. For instant, "hello" will not be selected when search for "he".

Is there anyway to search for exact match and replace with blank? how to include the word boundary? I have tried to place \b but it seems not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct. This needs `\b` (word boundaries).

```
prxid = prxparse('s/\b(?:you|i|we|they|he|she|it|etc)\b//');
call prxchange(prxid,-1,content);
```

using the non-capturing group `(?: ... )` to specify that the word boundaries are before and after any of the alternations.

Comment: Thank you! it works for me.. I have one more question, what if the word that i wanted to match is "don't". It will remove "don" only... " 't " will remains...

Comment: prxid = prxparse("s/\b(?<!' ')(?:(you|you%'re))\b(?!' ')/!/"); and prxid = prxparse("s/\b(?<!' ')(?:(you|you're))\b(?!' ')/!/"); but it seems not working...,

Comment: I missed out %str.. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: I see you've changed the quotation marks, so now there's no need to escape the single quotes: `prxid = prxparse("s/\b(?<!')(?:(you|you're))\b(?!')/!/i");`